# Change order of array of objects sorted by custom property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to write a script to change the order of an array of objects, ordered by an `order` property to let me move an element trough the array of objects I'm working on.

If I have:

```
[
  {order: 0, name: 'a'},
  {order: 1, name: 'b'},
  {order: 2, name: 'c'}
]
```

And I want to give to `b` the `order` `0`, the result of the function will be:

```
[
  {order: 0, name: 'b'},
  {order: 1, name: 'a'},,
  {order: 2, name: 'c'}
]
```

Other examples:

```
// a to pos 2
input = [
  {order: 0, name: 'a'},
  {order: 1, name: 'b'},
  {order: 2, name: 'c'}
]

output = [
  {order: 2, name: 'a'},
  {order: 0, name: 'b'},
  {order: 1, name: 'c'}
]

// c to pos 1
input = [
  {order: 0, name: 'a'},
  {order: 1, name: 'b'},
  {order: 2, name: 'c'}
]

output = [
  {order: 0, name: 'a'},
  {order: 1, name: 'c'},
  {order: 2, name: 'b'}
]
```

This is my script so far:

```
var movedColumn         = { order: 4, name: 'd' };
var newIndex            = 1;
var oldIndex            = movedColumn.order;
var columns             = [ { order: 0, name: 'a' }, { order: 1, name: 'b' }, { order: 2, name: 'c' }, { order: 3, name: 'd' }, { order: 4, name: 'e' }, { order: 5, name: 'f' } ];

columns.sort(function asc(a, b) { return a.order - b.order; }).forEach(function(column) {
  if (column.order >= newIndex && column.order < oldIndex) {
    column.order += 1;
  }
});
columns.find(function(column) {
  return column.name === movedColumn.name;
}).order = newIndex;
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/XXgxWe?editors=001

It works well when I want to move `b` to `order` `0`, but it doesn't work well if I want to move `a` to `order` `1`.
I don't care about the order of the objects in the array, in my script I order them just to "pretty print" the result and for clarity.
What matters is the value of the `order` properties.

How can I fix it?

### short version

I need to take an object and move it in the position defined by `newIndex`, shifting all the elements to prevent collisions (same order on two different objects)

Comment: This makes my head hurt, why would you move `b` up without changing the order, and what's it supposed to be sorted by ?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more examples of starting arrays and your desired results. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Pointy I've improved the input/ouput example

Comment: @adeneo those objects will be rendered in the order defined by the `order` key, this is why I don't care about the order of them in the array but I care only about what `order` says.

Comment: I would recommend to use `splice` or do it manually with a `for` loop, and not use the `sort` method

Comment: @Bergi **as written**, the sort part is just for clarity but is not the purpose of this script.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a solution:

```
var movedColumn         = { order: 5, name: 'f' };
var newIndex            = 4;
var oldIndex            = movedColumn.order;
var columns             = [ { order: 0, name: 'a' }, { order: 1, name: 'b' }, { order: 2, name: 'c' }, { order: 3, name: 'd' }, { order: 4, name: 'e' }, { order: 5, name: 'f' } ];

columns.sort(function asc(a, b) { return a.order - b.order; }).forEach(function(column) {
  if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    if (column.order >= newIndex && column.order < oldIndex) {
      column.order += 1;
    }
  }
  if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
    if (column.order > oldIndex && column.order <= newIndex) {
      column.order -= 1;
    }
  }
});
columns.find(function(column) {
  return column.name === movedColumn.name;
}).order = newIndex;
```

It seems to work in both the directions, it's not nice to see but it does the job.

Logically it will do nothing if you try to move the element to its very same order.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `column.order > oldIndex && column.order <= newIndex`?

Comment: It works in the way I've posted. You can try it [here](http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/Rrgeyw?editors=001) let me know if there's something wrong please.

Comment: Yes, it really doesn't work when you move something upwards by more than 1 ([example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLZQNG?editors=001)). Please *test* instead of only trying :-)